# Feature collection products are not displaying in the frontend in Shopify

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-template

I am new in Shopify. I am using Shopify default theme. Everything is working perfectly. I want to know about the collection. I added the more than 20 products in the collection. Now how do I display that all the products on my index page?

In the below image I have to display all my collection product. Now It is displaying the only template collection.
[image]

I clicked on customized and I got

[image]

Inside feature collection, I am getting the option

[image]

But still, my collection not displaying on the page. Would you help me out in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site does not seems to have any products in it. Please add products to your store and then try adding collections.
I have attached the screenshot of the page where to add products.

[image]

Comment: I have added new sample product in your store named "Shirt" and linked it with Home Page collection. Now you can check on edit page of Home page Collection also on your storefront.

Comment: Thanks again, First I have to add my all the products in product section and then go to collection clicked on Home page and add my all the products there. Right?

Comment: Exactly, that is it. I have created some sample products in your store. You can try add those products to your collections with the dropdown.

Comment: Cool! I will try it. Give me some time.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried whatever you suggested me. and it's working.

Comment: Do you have any notes, video, any link where I can learn more about Shopify?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168101/discussion-between-user9437856-and-sowmiya-sangaiah).

Comment: can you help me out in this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669197/how-to-display-single-product-tag-name-in-shopify

Answer (score 0):

Kindly assign products to Home Page collection with the following steps:

1. Click on Products tab on your left side menu in shopify admin.
2. Select Collections sub tab lying under products as shown below.[image]

You will be listed with the collections in your store. Edit the collection by clicking on it. Select the appropriate products you wish to list under collection in the field provided as shown below.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply @Sowmiya, I have to display the main product. I mean I have to display the 20 products which are in the collection.

Comment: As you said, if you have products assigned for Home page collections then am sure it should display in your frontend.
It may be foolish, but can u pls check at once whether you have saved your changes after customizing your theme.

Comment: If I add the products in the in the Home page then that will be sub products for the home page. right?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/izlks8 I am trying to add the product in Homepage but  there is no option to add it

Comment: http://prntscr.com/izlmkl  This is the products which I added to the collection. Now I have to display this product on the index page.

Comment: I hope there is no products been added yet in your collection from the first screenshot. Try typing the products name in the auto search field provided. 

It will display the list of products in dropdown. Choose the one you want to add to the collections and then save the collection.

Comment: I will tell you how I created the collection. First I clicked on "Product->collections->Create Collection"  then I added the title, description, and Image. Regarding condition, I set manually and I clicked on Save collection. I did this process 20 times because I have 20 products. but my products are not displaying in the front end.

Comment: You are right. At once you clicked on save you will be displayed with the option for selecting the products, right?  have you added products in that autosearch field provided

Comment: I have homepage collection in the collection list. I clicked on it and I am not getting the product name in the auto search. When I am entering the product name it's showing loading popup but not displaying the product name. but in the collection list showing my all the products

Comment: Please help me out on this issue. I am facing this issue from last 4-5 days.