# How to display single product tag name in Shopify?

Tags: tags, shopify, product

I have more than 20 products and each product have 2-3 tags.
I am displaying all the product tags using this code

```
  {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
  {% assign products_count = 0 %}
  {% for product in collection.products %}
  {% if product.tags contains tag %}
        {% assign products_count = products_count | plus: 1 %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

   <a class="filter__link" href="/collections/{% if collection.handle != blank %}{{ collection.handle }}{% else %}all{% endif %}/{{ tag | handleize }}"{% if current_tags contains tag %} selected="selected" id="tag_active"{% endif %}>{{ tag }} ({{products_count }})</a>
{% endfor %}
```

And output I am getting it

```
Apple(3)
mango(2)
banana(3)
```

Now I have to show the one tag name over the image. I am not getting it. If I clicked on any tag name (which I am getting in above output) then I am getitng the one tag name over image using below code.

```
{% for tag in product.tags %}
       {% if current_tags contains tag %}
       <a class="link" href="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">{{ tag | link_to_tag: tag }}</a>
   {% endif %}

   {% endfor %}
```

Would you help me out in this?

I need an output like this but I am getting blank tag over image
[image]

This output I am getting to click on Apple which is correct.
[image]

Comment: On what basis, you want to show only one tag?. something like, first tag, last tag or the one with particular name?

Comment: @SowmiyaSangaiah, I just updated my code.

Comment: @SowmiyaSangaiah, I hope this time you can understand my issue.

Comment: @SowmiyaSangaiah, What else part I have to use to display the tag in my second code?

Comment: i was not clear with your requirement. could you pls make it bit clear.

Comment: @SowmiyaSangaiah, please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707187/current-tag-displaying-more-than-one-tag-name-in-shopify

Comment: You will get an idea. What I am asking.