# Current tag displaying more than one tag name in Shopify

Tags: if-statement, tags, shopify, product

I am displaying the product tags. If the user clicked on `All products filter` then It will display only first single tag. If the user clicks on any current tag then it will display on the current tag name.

```
  {% for tag in product.tags %}
     {% if current_tags contains tag %}
     <a class="link" href="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">{{ tag | link_to_tag: tag }}</a>

   {% else %}
   <a class="link" href="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">{{ product.tags[0] | link_to_tag: tag }}</a>
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
```

Above code is displaying all the tag

My logic is

```
for(display all tag){
if(clicked current tag){
   display current tag name which is clicked
}
else{
display first tag name
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, else part is not working. I mean It's displaying all the tags . I need only single tag or first tag

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with the following:

```
{% assign product_tags = products | map: 'tags' %}
     {% if product_tags contains current_tags %}
     <a class="link" href="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">{{ current_tags | link_to_tag: current_tags }}</a>

   {% else %}
    {% assign first_tag = product.tags | first %}
   <a class="link" href="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">{{ first_tag | link_to_tag: first_tag }}</a>
     {% endif %}
```

Try updating this code in your required place and let me know whether you got the result.

Comment: There is some issue with current tag Liquid error (product-card-grid line 6): tag filter argument must be a string or tag

Comment: Else part is working but when I clicked on tag then current tag not displaying getting error

Comment: I have only three tags which are apple, mango, banana. So I clicked on apple and I got an error

Comment: just give me 10 min I will share with you

Comment: You have to click on collection_1_images and you will get two products in the top of the product image you will get first tag name which is correct. Now click on kivi_tag in filter section you will get two product but this time tag name is kivi_2_tag and kivi_1_tag. I need kivi_tag over images

Comment: I was unable to login to ur store

Comment: Yeah got it pls remove teh credentials from comment

Comment: Hope you understand my issue.

Comment: Yeah let me check and tell u.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168553/discussion-between-user9437856-and-sowmiya-sangaiah).

Comment: Can you help me out in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768814/tag-count-automatically-changing-while-clicking-on-the-product-tag