# Tag count automatically changing while clicking on the product tag

Tags: tags, shopify

I am using Shopify. I am in collection page where I am getting all the filter with tag count something like,

```
All Products
Apple(4)
Banana(2)
Orange(1)
Mango(8)
```

Now when I click on any of the tag(For example I clicked on Banana) then It will display the banana products.

Now my issue is by clicking on the tag it's changing the tag count.

```
All Products
Apple(0)
Banana(2)
Orange(0)
Mango(4)
```

I am using below code

```
 {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
 {% assign products_count = 0 %}
 {% for product in collection.products %}
 {% if product.tags contains tag %}
 {% assign products_count = products_count | plus: 1 %}
 {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 <a class="filter__link" href="/collections/{% if collection.handle != blank %}{{ collection.handle }}{% else %}all{% endif %}/{{ tag | handleize }}"{% if current_tags contains tag %} selected="selected" id="tag_active"{% endif %}>{{ tag }} ({{products_count }})</a>
  {% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first assignment {% assign products_count = 0 %} should be outside the loop. Then, question: is there more than 50 products in your collection?

Comment: @AliceGirard, Thanks for the reply, No I have only 20 products

Comment: I added outside of the loop {% assign products_count = 0 %} and this time I got wrong tag count.

Comment: @AliceGirard, any more help in this?

Comment: Yess, my mistake for the assignment, of course. It must be reset each time, you were right. Sorry for that. About error you get it's normal. It's because even if you loop through collection.all_tags, your secondary loop is processed based upon your current view which does not contains tags like apple or Orange.

Comment: @AliceGirard, Any more help in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the step you're missing is the first line [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24176617/1367622):

```
{% assign collection = collections.all %}
```

You're iterating over the current collection, so as you've noticed when you click on a tag the results change.

If you don't have a collection with the handle `all`, you can create one by following [this process](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/collections/change-catalog-page):

1. Go to Products > Collections.
2. Click Add a collection.
3. Create the collection:

   1. Give your collection the Title `All`.
   2. In the Conditions section, select "Automatically select products based on conditions".
   3. Set the product condition "Product price is greater than $0".
4. Save

**Edit:**

This fixes the issue where the product count changes when you click on a tag link:

```
{% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
    {% assign products_count = 0 %}
    {% for product in collections[collection.handle].products %}
        {% if product.tags contains tag %}
            {% assign products_count = products_count | plus: 1 %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <a class="filter__link" href="/collections/{% if collection.handle != blank %}{{ collection.handle }}{% else %}all{% endif %}/{{ tag | handleize }}"{% if current_tags contains tag %} selected="selected" id="tag_active"{% endif %}>{{ tag }} ({{products_count }})</a>
{% endfor %}
```

The key part is:

```
{% for product in collections[collection.handle].products %}
```

It looks like when you're filtering by tag with a URL like `collections/collection_1/tag_1` then `collection.products` is also filtered by the selected tag. The line above looks a bit messy, but it appears to return the full set of products.

Comment: I added your whole code count issue got resolved but filter not working. I mean if I clicked on any tag it's also displaying all the products.

Comment: I added this line    <a class="filter__link" href="/collections/{% if collection.handle != blank %}{{ collection.handle }}{% else %}all{% endif %}/{{ tag | handleize }}"{% if current_tags contains tag %} selected="selected" id="tag_active"{% endif %}>{{ tag }} ({{products_count }})</a> instated of this     <p>{{ tag }} ({{ products_count }})</p>

Comment: If I am adding this line {% assign collection = collections.all %} and click on filter tag then it's also displaying the remaining product which is not related to the tag.

Comment: Maybe the `collection` variable is conflicting with other code you have on the page referencing the current collection. I'd try renaming it to something like `all_collections` to see if that helps. One other idea could be to use [link_to_tag](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/url-filters#link_to_tag) (although your link looks like it should work ok).

Comment: I added below code to display the tag related products when user clicks on the tag    {% if current_tags %}
   {% for tag in product.tags %} 
      {% if current_tags contains tag %} 
          <a class="link" href="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">{{ tag | link_to_tag: tag }}</a> 
      {% endif %} 
   {% endfor %}
   {% else %}
   {% unless product.tags == empty %}
   {% assign first_tag = product.tags | first %}
      <a class="link" href="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">{{ first_tag | link_to_tag: first_tag }}</a> 
   {% endunless %}
   {% endif %}

Comment: Can you help me out is there any issue with it? because I added your code and it's displaying my products tag with count but there is some issue with displaying the products. It's displaying all the products when clicking on the product tag.

Comment: Renaming the variable to something like `{% assign all_collections = collections.all %}` didn't stop it from displaying all products?

Comment: I added your code but still facing tag count issue.

Comment: My demo store link is https://404demo.myshopify.com and username:-naren22jan@gmail.com and password is Pass#@123  and my store check password is drauld

Comment: In the collection  I click on  collection and it's displaying all the product and left side fillter tag I click on Product_1 and it's chnaging the product tag counts.Can you help me out in this issue.

Comment: Yes this time it's working perfectly.Realy appreciate your support and help. Thank you very much. Upvote from my side.

Comment: I just want to know why is my pagination not displaying there?

Answer (score 0):

As I was saying in comment, the issue comes from your secondary loop:

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
```

Which accesses only to the current view and not the full collection products.

I've not tested it but I guess it worthes a try:

```
{% assign whole_collection = collections[collection.handle] %}
{% for product in whole_collection.products %}
 {% if product.tags contains tag %}
 {% assign products_count = products_count | plus: 1 %}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Explanation, a code like this {{ collections['the-handle'].url }} allows access to any specific collection and its attributes.

HTH

Memo : this won't work accurately if your collection has more than 50 items.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I tried your code but it's not displaying my tag name. I just copy and paste your code.

Comment: Be sure to paste this snippet inside your loop  {% for tag in collection.all_tags %} and keep your count where it was {% assign products_count = 0 %}.

Comment: I added code but it's still not displaying it. Can you help me out where I am wrong?  {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
                   
                    {% assign whole_collection = collections[collection.handle] %}
{% for product in whole_collection.products %}
 {% if product.tags contains tag %}
 {% assign products_count = products_count | plus: 1 %}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

                    {% endfor %}